# Does zoom record multiple tracks seperately as different files?

Tags: field-recording, zoom-h4n, multichannel

How do I record audio on Zoom H4N with multiple Shotgun Mics or Lavalier Mics and have different files so I can edit/sync them separately later for my film?

Answer (score 2):

The recorder supports 3 different recording modes:

- **Stereo**: either the build-in mics OR external inputs)
- **4CH**: a stereo file for the build in mics AND another stereo file for the external inputs)
- **MTR**: Custom mono/stereo setup for all 4 channels.

**MTR Mode** is probably the one you want to go for. In MTR mode, you can send any input to any track. For example you may set it up with the build in mics recording in stereo (you can use this for an ambient combined recording) and the external mics recording 2x mono with the shotguns/lavaliers.

[image]